# Facebook iOS SDK: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm pretty much having the same issue as this post: [iOS Facebook SDK: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127282/ios-facebook-sdk-an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about), but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

Earlier in the method I call this:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_photos",
                        @"user_status",
                        @"read_stream",
                        nil];

self.fb = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
[self.fb openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                     FBSessionState status,
                                     NSError *error)
 {
     if(!error){
    NSLog(@"Facebook Authorized");
}
     if(error){

         NSLog(@"Error in fb auth request: %@", error.localizedDescription);

     }
        }];
```

And I successfully login with user access. Then, I need to get the users recent posts, so I do this: (FQL)

```
NSMutableArray *postIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSString *query = @"SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 10";

//this was the solution the other SO answer had.
[FBSession setActiveSession:self.fb];

// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                                                       if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else if(!error) {

                                NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                            NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *)result;
                              NSArray *postArr = [resultDict objectForKey:@"data"];

                              for (FBGraphObject *friendObj in postArr) {
                                  NSString *postIDString = [friendObj objectForKey:@"post_id"];
                                  [postIDArray addObject:postIDString];
                              }

                              NSLog(@"postidarray array  : %@", postIDArray);

                              //with post ids, loop through and use graph api to get the post details.
                              for (int i = 0; i <= postIDArray.count; i++) {

                                  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/%@",[postIDArray objectAtIndex:i] ];


                                  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                                  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
                                 NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:nil error:&error];
                                  NSDictionary *postDict = [result yajl_JSON];
                                  NSLog(@"post %d contents: %@",i, postDict);
                                  }
                }
                      }];
        }
```

I can get the post_ID's fine, but then when I try to call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/<my_post_id>
```

the returned data is:

```
  error =     {
    code = 2500;
    message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
    type = OAuthException;
};
}
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I tried to use

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:postIDString id result, NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                } else if(!error) { 
//do some parsing stuff
```

}

But I get this error:
    Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Comment: The issue is that NSMutableURLRequest doesn't add the access token from the active session. Why not use FBRequestConnection as you do above, and use @"me/<post_id>" as the graphPath?

Comment: Ok, so I tried   `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:postIDString
                                                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                                id result,
                                                                                NSError *error) {`  but it gives me `com.facebook.sdk error 5.)`

Comment: Oops. the call should not have the /me.

Comment: Did you get answer of this?